# Attach to Process in VS & Stack Trace

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

What does it mean when you see a .NET exe running but when you attach to the process using VS and look at all the threads there is no stack trace for any of the threads. It doesn't even say "[External Code]". It is just blank for all the threads. What could it be doing?

Comment: What are the thread names? Are you sure that you attached the right version of the .Net debugger?

Comment: Just for case. Has execution been stopped?

Comment: I see [Main] and some others. Went through all of them, same story. The program is still running.